# Successful build job in Jenkins is voting "Verify +1 Verify -1" in a Gerrit review

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

Initially Jenkins build failed and Jenkins votes "verify -1" in Gerrit. Then afterwards even if build is successful, it votes "Verify +1 verify -1". Because of vote we are not able to approve the change and not able to submit the code.

```
Patch Set 3: Verify+1 Verify-1
Build Successful 
https://review.example.com/job/job_name/number/ : SUCCESS
```

Versions:

```
Jenkins               = 2.19.2
Gerrit server         = 2.13.3
Gerrit trigger plugin = 2.22.0
```

Initially it was working fine. But suddenly it started working abnormally. Please provide any important settings to be done here.

**One more observation:** I see this behaviour only when the build is triggered via "Query and gerrit trigger patch" option and "Retrigger" option in Jenkins. It is working fine if you amend the commit and push to gerrit server as new patch set for the same change.

Did anyone come across this issue?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue using almost the same configuration (Jenkins 2.19.2, Gerrit server 2.13.2 and Gerrit trigger 2.23.0). You could try to upgrade the Gerrit trigger just in case (I don't think this is the issue). Did you configure the Gerrit trigger to use SSH or REST?

Comment: Yes I have configured the Gerrit trigger to use SSH.

Comment: Also updated the question with my latest observation.